# How to make a Many to Many with same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm creating an API with ASP .NET CORE 6.0 and I also create a Many to Many with the same table (Users), the idea is that sponsors can sponsor one or more students and students can have one or more sponsors.

These are the tables and setup I already made.

Sponsors Table

```
   public class Sponsors
{
    [Key]
    public int SponsorhipId { get; set; }

    public string SponsorId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("SponsorId")]
    public  Users Sponsor { get; set; } = default!;

    public string SponsoredId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("SponsoredId")]
    public  Users Sponsored { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Users Table

```
   public class Users : IdentityUser
{

    [Required]
    public string IdentificationCard { get; set; } = default!;

    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string SecondName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string SecondLastName { get; set; } = default!;

    public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; } = default!;

    public int Age { get; set; } = default!;

    public Gender Gender { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Photo { get; set; } = default!;

    public States State { get; set; } = default!;

    public ContactMethods ContactMethods { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Address { get; set; } = default!;

    public Grades Grades { get; set; }

    public Sponsors? Sponsor1 { get; set; }

    public Sponsors? Sponsor2 { get; set; }

    public Comments? Comment1 { get; set; }

    public Comments? Comment2 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Courses> Courses { get; set; } = default!;

    public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }

}
```

ModelCreating of ApplicationDbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Users>().HasIndex(u => u.IdentificationCard).IsUnique();

        builder.Entity<Sponsors>()
               .HasOne(m => m.Sponsor)
               .WithOne(t => t.Sponsor1)
               .HasForeignKey<Sponsors>(m => m.SponsorId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<Sponsors>()
                    .HasOne(m => m.Sponsored)
                    .WithOne(t => t.Sponsor2)
                    .HasForeignKey<Sponsors>(m => m.SponsoredId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


    }
```

The problem is that right now a Sponsor can only have a relationship with a Student and viceversa.

Any idea how can I modify this to allow a Sponsor have one or more relationships with a Student and viceversa?

Thanks

Comment: I found this, not sure if it helps https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: You need a junction table that holds both PKs

Comment: @GHDevOps that was my first thought too, but it looks like `EntityFramework` will automatically scaffold that relationship table for you. if I read the link right.

Comment: You can do it implicitly or explicitly. I'd rather have my class and table.

Comment: I tried already with that but the migration always failed so I did differently. I think is maybe because students and sponsors are from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with EF Core 5.0, many-to-many relationships are supported without explicit mapping of the join table. EntityFramework will automatically create a join table for you if you have a collection navigation property in both entities.
In your use case it would look like this (I left out some properties for the sake of simplicity).

```
public class Sponsor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Sponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
    }
}
```

[image: Database Schema]

Comment: Hi, the issue is that sponsors and students are from the same table, which is Users, the role defines what type of user is